# Passing data from collection view to detail view

Tags: ios, image, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I need some help figuring out how to pass data from my collection view to the detail view controller. I am starting by simply passing the image through. My code is below:

ViewController:

```
    -(MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *imageObject = [imageFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    __block UIImage *MyPicture = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"test"];


    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            cell.CollectionImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            cell.cellLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"phone"];

        }
    }];

    return cell;
}

 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        TopDetailViewController *detailVC = [[TopDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        detailVC.img= [imageFilesArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
    }
```

And the Detail view:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSString *img;
```

.m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.img];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

If someone could help me out I would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use [UIImage imageNamed:] to retrieve images that are in your app bundle. It looks like you create these images at run-time based on the PDF file, so just passing in the string to the detail view and loading it with [UIImage imageNamed:] won't work. You should pass the reference to the image or the PFFile object so that the detail view can generate the image itself.

Comment: So how would I write that out? I cannot call the object in the new Detail View Controller. I appreciate the help I am still fairly new to Xcode

Comment: You have an "NSString *img" ivar in DetailViewController, right? Just create another one that is "UIImage *actualImage", and pass it along the same way.